# Why is Visual Studio 2017 F1 showing Windows 8 Phone documentation?

Tags: visual-studio

I have created a C# class library in Visual Studio Community 2017. Here's the content of one of my files:

```c#
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace ExLumina.Stevens.Midi
{
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct MidiHdr
    {
        public IntPtr lpData;
        public int dwBufferLength;
        public int dwBytesRecorded;
        public int dwUser;
        public int dwFlags;
        public IntPtr lpNext;
        public int reserved;
        public int dwOffset;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 8)]
        public int[] dwReserved;
    }
}
```

When I put the insertion cursor in the `IntPtr` string and press `F1`, I see the help page here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.intptr?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.IntPtr);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.7);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue%26f%3D255%26MSPPError%3D-2147217396&view=netframework-4.7.1

That's fine by me.

But, when I put the cursor on the `UnmanagedType` string and press `F1`, it takes me here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/apps/8c0157f5(v=vs.105)?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework%2CVersion%3Dv4.7)%3Bk(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue

That's a Windows 8 Phone page marked as no longer updated. (Note the substring `previous-versions` in the URL.)

Why is it doing this and how can I get it to use the same documentation set as when I use `F1` on `IntPtr`? Thanks for any help!

Comment: Use Help > Send Feedback > Report a Problem.

Comment: Like @HansPassant suggested, please open an issue. Microsoft is migrating their documentation to the new site, so some links can easily be broken by mistake.

Comment: Appears I'm not the first to tell them about it. My version is not the latest, so maybe it's fixed already? Downloading now, but it's slow. If the latest update includes a fix, I'll say so here.

Comment: UPDATE: Latest version, 15.5.2, shows the same incorrect behavior. Several users have reported this, some as recently as today. MS appears to have thought they solved the problem a couple of weeks ago, but they haven't. One report from 01 JAN 2018 is marked "Triaged," so perhaps they will (think they) have fixed it again soon.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to a bug [reported to MS](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/175093/f1-help-launches-obsolete-docs-page.html) by multiple users and acknowledged by MS. Upvoting it might be a good idea.